# A little confused on this stream readable syntax

Tags: node.js, express, stream

I read through the stream handbook and they had this example:

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;

var rs = new Readable;
rs.push('beep ');
rs.push('boop\n');
rs.push(null);

rs.pipe(process.stdout);
```

It looks like exactly what I needed (push objects into a readable stream and pipe it to a writable.)

So this is what I came up with

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var rs = new Readable;

app.get('/:foo', function(req, res) {
oboe(fs.createReadStream("/file"))
    .node( "{}", function(data) { 
          rs.push(data) 
     })
rs.pipe(res);
```

I am using oboe to listen on the fsStream for objects and modifying them. Currently I am pushing the newly found objects into an array and then on "done" stream event I would tell express to res.json the newly created array. This got too memory heavy and i was wondering if I could just empty the stream as the objects are found and modified, push it into a readable and as the readable stream gets data, it would pipe it out to res but still maintain one object.

However I was receiving this error

```
Error: not implemented at Readable._read
```

Does this mean the stream handbook is out of date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to use `Readable` directly. You're supposed to subclass it and write your own implementation of `_read`; that's why node is complaining that `Readable._read` is not implemented. Also, node streams want `String`s or `Buffer`s, not `JSON Object`s, so writing `data` from oboe's `node` event to a stream will probably cause problems.

I think there's an easier solution than using a `Readable` stream here. It sounds like you want to take the `JSON Object` that oboe is giving you, change it, and stream it out express's `res` object. `res` itself is a `Writable` stream so, instead of going through an intermediary stream, you can simply `write` to it as many times as you'd like until you're done. Be aware though that you'll also have to call `end()` on the response stream (`res`) when when oboe is finished.

```
app.get('/:foo', function(req, res) {
    oboe(fs.createReadStream("/file"))
        .node( "{}", function(data) { 
            // ... transform data however you need ...
            res.write(JSON.stringify(data)); // Note that data is JSON.stringified here since res.write wants a String or a Buffer, not an Object
        })
        .done(function() {
            res.end();
        })
})
```

**Note:** *I'm assuming you have something on the other end of the response that can handle getting JSON Objects streamed in like that. You'll probably need something like oboe on that end too, if you don't have it already.*

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you, it makes a lot of sense now. I am however now having res.write construct the json object. So res.write("["); then after each stringify(data) i added +"," and then at the end before res.end it adds the ending ]. A trailing Comma doesnt seem to be an issue in IE9 so I am going to try this out and see if my front end can handle this stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I am running into troubles now.
Oboe on the front end says it does not see an object but my network in dev tools clearly show a successful get of my json with proper headers from Express as well. I did the same with an Ajax call and the response inside AJAX has the full object additionally to my network showing a proper 200 response on a json object. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Are you sure that extra `,` isn't causing problems in Oboe on your front end?

Comment: Yea, Because its reading from a file that gets automatically written, to check to see if the comma was an issue, I forced the stream to read from an existing file instead and removed the comma there. and the JSON comes through as is. Still with the same problem.
A friend tells me it could be a dom issue and the fix is to have the ajax call inside a div so that dom recognizes it something? Im currently in the middle of finding more about that.

Comment: But the res.write is writing proper json objects to the HTTP request. Like I just went to Localhost and see my object load on screen, its there perfectly fine. But through any calls even through oboe, there are issues. I might be willing to try out other browser side json stream handlers before I make any more conclusions I suppose.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like the server side (node) is working fine but you might have some more issues to investigate on the front end. I'd suggest posting a new question regarding your front end issues and link to it here, that way it gets the most visibility and we don't end up with a huge comment thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447943/json-object-unusable-because-its-streamed-in

Comment: You were right, it was the trailing comma. While Browser did not care it was there and read the JSON still fine, when the AJAX call does it, it very much cares it is in perfect JSON format or else it has an unexpected error and emits error. I should have built my error loggers better at first because a `console.log(xhr + error + status);` helped reveal the problem.