# JSON Object unusable because its streamed in?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, stream

Reference for background

[A little confused on this stream readable syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428423/a-little-confused-on-this-stream-readable-syntax/25429528?noredirect=1#comment39683052_25429528)

The current situation is I am using res.write in express to write out the json object that is slowly being streamed by using JSON.Stringify.

```
app.get('/:foo', function (req, res) {
var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query(---SQL QUERY---);

res.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
res.header("Cache-Control", "max-age=3600");
res.write("[");

    request.on('row', function (data) {
        res.write(JSON.stringify(data)+",");
    )};
    request.on('done', function () {
        res.write("]");
        res.end();
    });
```

That is roughly the syntax I am using,

the Headers come through fine,

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Date: Fri, 22 Aug 2014 13:08:34 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

This call was done with an AJAX call and an [Oboe call](http://oboejs.com/api). The problem is even though this JSON shows up in my network as status 200, I cannot use it at all. Oboe emits a fail, and AJAX emits a fail as well.

A friend said it could be something to do with DOM timing but couldnt really explain it, he just said he knows sometimes his devs would encase the call in a `<div>` so it renders inside the dom and stays? I dont really understand what he means.

Should I be using something like jQuery Stream?

Previously when I had my JSON in a callback it was loading fine with the AJAX calls but writing the objects in a stream to res seems to cause it to break?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,

my JSON was adding a trailing comma.

While the browser does not care about a trailing comma and will read the object just fine, AJAX Call and Oboe.js Call simply fails with unexpected ]